# Woocommerce "Add to cart" not showing anymore

Tags: button, woocommerce

Hello I have a problem with the "Add to cart" button for variable products on my website. Here a link to one product: http://bit.ly/1RUoBQq

It worked, but now it doesn't and I don't know why!

-) I added wp_head and wp_footer in the files
-) I set prices for each variation
-) I deactivated all plugins, except of woocommerce

But problem is still there.

Using Woocommerce 2.4.7
Wordpress: 4.3.1

Thank you

Comment: I found this problem in the console: http://666kb.com/i/d33wc64qrfza9u55a.gif

Comment: Try using a default theme. Or use WooCommerce>System Status>tools>enable template debugging to use WooCommerce's default templates. You probably have an outdated theme template.